# Is it a good practice to use css grid for web applications (not websites)?

Tags: html, css, interface

I am developing a web application which is not an information conducting website like a blog, or news page or any other page where content matters. I am working on an application which is a tool and therefore will have multiple interface elements: data grids, buttons, input fields etc.

One of the designers told me that its a good practice to use 'css grid framework' to make my design based on some grid, however I have doubts because if I understand grids correctly, I then will be confounded to say 40px per column and if I have 2 x 15px buttons then I will have a hard time putting it all together within 'cells' of 40px...

In my mind grid is wasting lot of space and is good for big blocks of information but not for many little elements... am I correct?

Please let me know if its always a good practice to use grid or are there instances when actually good old pixel by pixel is simply better. If I am wrong please refer me to some good website which will explain how to use grids properly.

Comment: A grid doesn't mean every element should fit inside a 40x40 square, it means it should **align** to it. Which I personally think is *still* a waste of time and effort. There's a reason a document **flows**. Still. This is a "should I" question, which isn't constructive on [so]. Try the chat, or a forum.

Comment: You can get flexible grids, you don't have to conform to 40 by 40 blocks

Comment: You can do some pretty cool things with blocks, you can get them properly flowing with something like masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Madara, If my question is not good enough for Stack Overflow FORUM let me rephrase it... :)

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash: [so] is **not** a forum. Please read the **[FAQ]**.

Comment: @Madara, In that case can you recommend a good forum which can answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://grids.heroku.com/ its a simple tool that generates fixed or flexible grids. If you want to read up on how grids work, a simple and popular grid system is http://960.gs

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of the 960 grid is that it give you a large number of evenly divisible factors to allow for multiple **columns**. They're just guidelines to make it easy.

What you choose to put in these column is up to you. Your buttons don't need to conform to the grid.

Answer (score 2):

I can say that from my experience, grid systems make things much easier to design and then develop. From a design perspective, it's easier to know where and how things need to line up and then when you pass the designs off to a developer, he or she can just plug the design into the grid and everything lays out as expected.

A great grid framework for applications and websites is Twitter's Bootstrap. Looking at the [scaffolding page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem), you can see that it offers both a fixed grid layout and also a responsive layout. I prefer the responsive layout, but I build websites not web apps.  It's also great because it has built in styles for buttons that inherently fit into the grid, a JS library loaded with useful and easy to access functions and a great support network.

Other grid systems you might want to look at are:

[960.gs](http://960.gs/), [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and [1140 CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/). You can also Google for a grid generator to create your own custom layout.

Pick the one that works for you and the designer you'll work with and your lives will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, "always a good practice to use grid?" That's a rather open-ended question (and one of the reasons it's not a good fit for SO), but here is my two cents:

**A)** If quick and dirty UI is not only fine but expected and needed (say, for some internal function that doesn't get run very often), then go old-skool and dump something together that works.

**B)** If you are developing an app that "the public" or a fair amount of non-technical users will be leveraging, then you really should at least attempt to create a consistent layout for each view, which is where grid systems like 960 or Twitter Bootstrap shine. From personal experience, Bootstrap makes it really easy for me to get my navigation controls, datagrids, input forms, etc. to line up and position themselves correctly in the page.

The [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site could give you a better idea of when/why to use grids, and may actually be a better fit for this question anyway...